# Django SearchFilter, Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: django

I have model

```
class Emails(models.Model):
    mail_theme = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
```

in my view i have added

```
from rest_framework import filters
class EmailsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = EmailsSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('is_paid', 'new_item', 'mail_from')
    search_fields = 'mail_from'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Emails.objects.all()
```

but when i try to use `mail_from` field for search, i had an error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'm' into field. Choices are: id, mail_from
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [**`search_fields`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) should be a collection of strings, for example a singleton *tuple*. By writing it as a string, Django iterates over the characters, and thus assumes that `'m'`, `'a'`, `'i'`, etc. are all search fields:

```
from rest_framework import filters

class EmailsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = EmailsSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filter_fields = ('is_paid', 'new_item', 'mail_from')
    search_fields = ('mail_from',)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Emails.objects.all()
```